# Infinite loads on SharePoint Pages

Tags: performance, chrome, applicationcustomizers

I'm wondering if anyone else is experiencing the infinite load on SharePoint Online pages. It happens randomly on system (.aspx) pages such as the "Site Assets" library. There are no customizations on the pages leaving me to believe it is a bug.

How can I narrow down the cause, or should I write Microsoft? Closing and reopening the tab fixes it temporarily, but it returns after a while. The spinning icon in the tab keeps loading and I have no extensions installed in Chrome.

Comment: Do you experience this in all common browsers? It can't be a client-side issue like a Chrome Extension or something similiar? Are you sitting behind a proxy? Does this happen too if you access SPO from the internet with your own laptop?

Comment: Yes, all browsers. It looks like it is an application customizer installed by ShortPoint. Stay clear of these webparts & templates!